# Updated splash / launch not working

Tags: iphone, ios, image, splash-screen

I will add localization to the splash image from my app.

I created the images and put them in the correct folder, but when I launch the application "updating" my app in the simulator it still shows the old image.

I tried to cleand and build with no results.

If I delete my app and istall it again, it works fine!

I did a test in 2 iphones from my company and in both I got the same behavior, I have to delete and install the app to update the images.

My question is: This will happen when I update the app on the apple store? The users will continue to see the old splash image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users shouldn't see the old image when updating from the app store. From what I have seen and heard from others, the install process in the simulator from Xcode is more of a copy/paste action than and update/install action. As long as a clean run works fine, it should be safe to assume that your app store version will work fine as well.

Comment: Well, I hope it works. I did't found similar cases on internet, so things should work like you said. I think that the only way to know is testing it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rafael How did this turn out? I am experiencing the very same problem. Did the app store upgrade process automagically resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

One Suggestion.. if you just want to show **SPLASH PNG** image then just use **default.png** name of the splash image in you **Resource** folder... **Don't code anything** for splash png image...

iPhone will automatically detect this **default.png** as a splash image..

Comment: Yes, I already use Default.png as my splash image name. I created two Default.png files in their respective language folders. I don't know why my splash only update when I delete and install the app. Thanks for your time!

Comment: no you must keep in Resource folder directly without any folder structure... if you are using 2 different files then you have to code it...

Comment: Well, at Xcode if you click on a image, click on "+" at Localization tab and add the localizations you want, XCode automatically create language folders with the images. I just replaced the image for a specif language and its workin from a clean run. (All images have the same name)

Comment: at 2016 now it still solved my headage. thanks a ton